# Sequence of partial sums is Cauchy

Tags: cauchy-sequences, matrix-exponential

Trying to show that the matrix exponential $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{A^k}{k!} $converges because the sequence of partial sums $S_N=\sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{A^k}{k!} $ is Cauchy.

It is Cauchy, if
$$ \forall \varepsilon>0: \ \exists N_{\varepsilon}: \ N,\ M>N_{\varepsilon} \Longrightarrow \Vert S_M-S_N \Vert <\varepsilon. $$

So is this equivalent to showing that $$ \lim_{M,N \rightarrow \infty} \Vert S_M-S_N \Vert=0?$$

Comment: Are you taking your matrices to be real, complex or something else? Which matrix norm are you using? They converge regardless of which context you are in but I wanted to know your context.

Comment: @daruma So far I've been working with real matrices (when it comes to computing matrix exponentials). I prefer using, for example, $ \Vert \cdot \Vert_1 $ of $ \Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty} $ because then it's intuitive that the matrix converges element-wise.